# Use Xcode 10.1 with Swift 5

Tags: xcode

As I understand, working with Swift 5 requires Xcode 10.2, so I should upgrade my Xcode. But I am using hackintosh macOS 10.13.6 , the upgrade is very troublesome,because xcode10.2 requires macOS 10.14. so I want to stay with Xcode 10.1.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hope this will help you :
https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/a7bmh9/using_swift_50_in_xcode_101/ 
https://learningswift.brightdigit.com/swift-5-0-xcode-10-1/

Answer (score 1):

1.Download and Install the [Swift 5.0 Development Branch Toolchain.](https://swift.org/download/#releases)

2.Create Your Project or Target in Xcode 10.1

3.Go to the Top Menu and Select Xcode…Toolchains… Swift 5.0 Snapshot…

[Xcode Toolchain Menu Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4RjZ.png)